# How to assert a text field contains in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code I'm trying to assert that a text field contains "Post Published" I can't seem to figure it out

```
string actualvalue = driver.FindElement(By.Id("message")).Text;

actualvalue.Contains("Post published1.");
```

I'm not sure where to place my assertion.

Comment: Your assertion would come after `actualvalue.Contains("Post published1.");`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Assert.IsTrue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243754.aspx) for that

```
string actualvalue = driver.FindElement(By.Id("message")).Text;
Assert.IsTrue(actualvalue.Contains("Post published1."), actualvalue + " doesn't contains 'Post published1.'");
```

The message will be displayed only in case the assertion failed, i.e. `actualvalue` doesn't contains `"Post published1"`.