# How to Use Assert.Contain on C#, Selenium

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

How can I check if a name on a headline is the same as a specific text?

```
Assert.Contains("Text", _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div.content > header > h1")));
```

This is not correct :(.

Second question is, how can I choose (IWebElement and click on it) to open a dropdown menu? I tried finding the element through XPath, CssSelecton, TagName, etc, but nothing seems to happen.

The attribute from my question is:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link header-dropdown-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="cell">Обучения</span>
</a>
```

Comment: The link below should give you the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901716/how-to-assert-a-text-field-contains-in-selenium-c-sharp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901716/how-to-assert-a-text-field-contains-in-selenium-c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assert a text field contains in selenium c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901716/how-to-assert-a-text-field-contains-in-selenium-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this :

`Assert.AreEqual(text, driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div.content > header > h1")).Text);`

Or Contains :

`Assert.True(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div.content > header > h1")).Text.Contains("Text you want check"));`

Or Equals :

`Assert.True(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div.content > header > h1")).Text.Equals("Text you want check"));`

I hope this can help you.